# Unable to find 'swig.swg' and Unable to find 'python.swg

Tags: ros, debian, wheezy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I'm building a new Debian (wheezy) install.

Following the usual instructions. I've successfully built the swig app - swig.swg & python.swg exist in /swig/1.3.29.

Seems the build script can't find them - anyone any idea what's wrong? Output is:

```
'[ 61%] Generating rosout_panel_swig_generated.cpp, rxtoolscpp.py
:1: Error: Unable to find 'swig.swg'
:3: Error: Unable to find 'python.swg
/home/pi/ros-underlay/rx/rxtools/src/
rxtools/rxtools.i:2: Error: Unable to
find 'std_string.i'
/home/pi/ros-underlay/rx/rxtools/src/
rxtools/rxtools.i:13: Error: Unable to find 'typemaps.i'
/home/pi/ros-underlay/rx/wxPython_swig_interface/src/wxPython_swig_interface/core.i:25: Error: Unable to find '
typemaps.i'
make[2]: *** [rx/rxtools/rosout_panel_swig_generated.cpp] Error 1
make[1]: *** [rx/rxtools/CMakeFiles/python_rxtools.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Thanks

Mark

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36890/unable-to-find-%27swig.swg%27--and-unable-to-find-%27python.swg/) by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1834 on 2012-06-20

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Okay found the problem. For some reason the swig installation script thought is had installaed the lib at /usr/local/share/swig/... (Which is normal) however the actual files were in /swig i.e. off top level dir.

Solution

cp -r /swig /usr/local/share

and get on with the build.

---

Originally posted by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) with karma: 1834 on 2012-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [spiffytech](https://answers.ros.org/users/5785/spiffytech/) on 2013-08-06**:
If you don't want to copy the files to the wider filesystem, you can pass swig the -I option to specify where to look for your .swg files:

swig-2.0.10/swig -go -intgosize 64 -Iswig-2.0.10/Lib -Iswig-2.0.10/Lib/go example.i